# Does Ni-CD battery chemistry lose its discharge amperage over time?

Tags: amperage, battery-chemistry, c-rate

I know with Li-Ion the amperage stays the same, right up until the end of its life, then the Amp Discharge rapidly goes down, But Does a Ni-Cd Battery Chemistry lose its discharge amperage over time? I know that it loses its charge sitting on the shelf, and requires maintenance, but does the Discharge Amps go down as the battery ages?

Comment: Your statement about lithium ion is incorrect.  Yes, NiCd loses capacity with age; pretty much *everything* does.  One major mechanism in NiCd is electrolyte loss from overcharging, but there are others.  No doubt someone will soon chime in with comments on "memory" which is only barely a real thing observed much more rarely than it is talked about...

Comment: Also "discharge amperage" is not really a meaningful term - it's not very clear if you are talking about *capacity* or about factors which influence how much *power* the cell can provide to a load at any given instant (ie, discharge C rating, internal resistance, etc)

Comment: @ChrisStratton True. But since batteries lose both their energy capacity and max current/power output as they age, the answer to OP's question is yes any way you spin it. Whatever the OP's question is, the answer is that everything about a battery gets worse as it ages.

Comment: Chris Stratton is absolute correct. The most vulnerable component to my knowledge is the electrodes in Li-Ion's, Ni-Cd Battery build crystals which limit their abilities over time